# XML Schema, One of each child element?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to define a schema that allows child elements to occur in any order, similar to `<choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">` but will allow only one of each element, similar to `<sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">`

can this be done?

for example

```
<Root>
 <ele1>
 <ele3>
 <ele2>
</Root>    <!--Valid-->
```

And as below:

```
<Root>
 <ele1>
 <ele1>
 <ele3> 
</Root> <!--Invalid-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xs:all rather than xs:sequence, so you'd write:

```
<xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="element1"/>
                <xs:element name="element2"/>
                <xs:element name="element3"/>
            </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: AHA! thanks. i discovered this as well in my testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `maxOccurs="1"` to the element.

Comment: i tried this several ways in several places, but it doesn't seem to be enforced. Maybe i did it wrong?